# How can I select multiple html elements of an array and set them all to a function at once?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've made a simple Whack-a-Mole kind of game with vanilla javascript and html, so I made an array with 9 button elements:

```
var buttons = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, 
button6, button7, button8, button9];
```

So when a mole appears in a button you click on it before it disappears:

```
if(button1.innerHTML === "MOLE!"){
    button1.onclick = function(){
        score+=500;
        scoreR.innerHTML = "              SCORE:" + (score);    
        button1.innerHTML = "Empty Hole";
    }
}else{
    button1.onclick = function(){
        score-=2000;
        scoreR.innerHTML = "              SCORE:" + (score);
    }

}
```

I want to know if instead of repeating that if/else 9 times per button, there is a way of optimize the code, like applying a single function to all the 9 elements of the array at once (?)

Comment: [Yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are new to javascript, so a for-loop should do the trick in a way you can understand without too many changes in your code. In a later time you can opt for other solutions that rely on advanced javascript techniques.

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i]; //this var holds the current button to which the events will be set

    //here comes your code, with 'button' instead of 'button1':
    if(button.innerHTML === "MOLE!"){
        button.onclick = function(){
            score+=500;
            scoreR.innerHTML = "              SCORE:" + (score);    
            button.innerHTML = "Empty Hole";
        }
    }else{
        button.onclick = function(){
            score-=2000;
            scoreR.innerHTML = "              SCORE:" + (score);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and yes, I'm trying to become better at this lol, thanks again man that looks neat.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend on all the button elements you add an `onClick` to call the function below like:

```
<button onClick="checkForMole(this)">
```

We pass 'this' in so we can write one function and use it dynamically.

In javascript then:

```
function checkForMole(button) {
    // boolean isMole
    var isMole = button.innerHTML === "MOLE!";
    if (isMole) {
      score += 500;
      refreshScoreElement();   
      button.innerHTML = "Empty Hole";
    } else {
      score -= 2000;
      refreshScoreElement();
    }
}

function refreshScoreElement() {
    scoreR.innerHTML = "              SCORE:" + (score);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to wrap that array of button inside a `div` tag, then you can `addEventListener` to that `div`, in the callback method, you check whether the target is the button and you can have further action with it after that. I create a simple sample as below

```js
var foo = document.querySelector(".js_mole");
foo.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.tagName==="BUTTON"){
    var lableText = target.innerHTML;
    var dataId = target.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log('ID:' + dataId + '- lableText:' + lableText);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="js_mole">
    <button class="button" data-id="js_mole_1">1</button>
    <button class="button" data-id="js_mole_3">3</button>
    <button class="button" data-id="js_mole_2">2</button>
</div>
```